# Obtaining the distribution of upvotes on questions for specific Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, questions, score

I'm wondering if there any way to obtain, for a specific Stack Exchange site such as Philosophy, how many questions exist that have 0 upvotes, 1 upvote, -1, etc.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122477/274942.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily with a SEDE query - [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/philosophy/query/567249#resultSets) uses the score of a question instead of upvotes only, as I think that's what you're looking for.

[image]

For reference, here is the query. Please note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning.

```sql
SELECT Score, COUNT(*)
  FROM Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId = 1
  GROUP BY score
  ORDER BY score
```

Comment: Thanks! I run the query but there is a lot of rows of text as a result. I know, they are the information we are looking for, but... How to plot it? Do you had to use a external program?

Comment: You're welcome. Next to the Results tab, there's a Graph tab: http://data.stackexchange.com/philosophy/query/567249#graph

Comment: Yes, perfect, thank you! Actually it's very visible, I was a little blind when I didn't saw it.

Comment: results are likely skewed because there is no data on deleted posts - if I understand correctly [PostsWithDeleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/165773) has the information about score and could be used instead of Posts in such SEDE queries

Comment: @gnat yes, but one could argue that deleted posts don't exist anymore and should not be included in the results.

Comment: many deleted posts hang on a site for quite a while, this may impact voting on other posts (through daily vote limit) and perception of users who observe site front page. What was distribution of votes [at MSE on Apr 21, 2016](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pWwhs.png)?